# How to delete an administrator account (Windows 8)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, user-accounts

I use Windows 8 with Windows 7-like GUI, classic shell

I have two administrative accounts: `user` and `Administrator`.

I am currently `user`

`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\User Accounts\Manage Accounts\Change an Account` does not show "Delete" button:

[image]

I run cmd with administrative privileges and executed

`net user Administrator /active:no`

`net user Administrator [/DELETE]`

Both times I got "The command has completed successfully" message, but `Administrator` is still visible under `Manage Accounts` menu.

When I execute these commands again, I get the same message.

Comment: The built-in administrator account is a special account. Removing it *may* lead to undesired behavior. Instead, tell us what makes you want to delete this account.

Comment: It was added by service center which repaired my laptop, because, they didn'y have password from mine. Everything seems to work fine after deletion.

Comment: No, it wasn’t. It’s always there but usually invisible.

Comment: @user2136963 - They didn't "add" the account.  They just activated the account.  Just deactivate the account, numerous tutorials that exist, on how to activate and deactivate this account.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you want to delete the account, or just disable it. So, below are how to do both. For both, there are three common steps. Then, they branch out as outlined.

It is recommended that you do *not* delete the Administrator account, though, as it is built in for certain things. But, if you know what you are doing, deleting it should be fine.

**Common Steps**

1. Open the Run Dialog with `WIN`+`R`.
2. Type and enter in `lusrmgr.msc`.
3. Go into the `Users` part.

**Method 1 : Delete the Account**

4. Find and delete the Account you want to delete.

**Method 2 : Disable the Account**

4. Find and Right Click the Account you want to disable.
5. Select Properties.
6. Check "Account is Disabled" and click Apply.

Answer (score 0):

The Admin account cannot be deleted unless you have another account with Administrative privileges. To do just that, follow these steps:

1. Make a new account from admin account.
2. Log off change user.
3. Log on to new account.
4. Delete old account.